# Determining flat screen percentage in PDFs

Tags: adobe-indesign, adobe-acrobat

[image: InDesign screening]

In the attached image, the designer has created the screening with effects > transparency, as opposed to just using a percentage of the color used.
Is there a way to determining the percentage of opacity used when just supplied with a PDF?
Bonus question - why would someone do it that way?
I do have Pitstop tools, but cannot find a way with that, either.
Thanks!

Comment: Global 7% tint = 100% color @ 7% opacity.

Comment: The percentages (25 - 35%   7%) in the bar are part of the artwork in that chart - they have no bearing on the screen.
The 75C 68M 87Y 90K is a color commonly seen with some clients who work in RGB mode.

Comment: It's merely a rich black. Do you have your own formula for rich black?

Comment: Why would someone create a transparency effect using transparency? Erm… because that’s how you normally do transparency? It’s impossible to tell from the tiny sample given here, but if the background is not just a flat colour and is supposed to be visible through the coloured bar, transparency is the only sane option.

Comment: @Scott I think you’re misunderstanding the question here. It’s not about whether they have a different formula for rich black, nor indeed about rich black at all. In the PDF seen behind the Enfocus window, the sandy-coloured bar containing the text “25 - 35% … 7%” has a background defined as CMYK 75/68/67/90 (a CMYK rich black, but could be any colour in any colour mode really). It has an opacity significantly lower than 100%; the question is how to find, from the PDF file itself, what this opacity actually is.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet i think with this info alone you can not

Comment: @Scott - Our standard rich black is 60C 40M 40Y 100K for sheetfed & 40C 30M 30Y 100K for web. Most rich blacks I've used or encountered over the years have the black at 100%.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet my question would be more like why would someone make a flat tint of a color by using transparency. If they wanted a 15 or 20% black bar, they could have done it the simpler way, where it would have shown as the percentage of the color when checking the PDF..If I could add a pic at this point, I'd show you what I mean.

Comment: I don't have access to PitStop right now, but I think it's possible to read the opacity somewhere. Perhaps under the 5th tab (with checkered background)? Besides that I believe PitStop has a color picker tool to grab the resulting percentage. Furthermore you could open *Output Preview*, make sure the *Simulation Profile* is correct (unless the PDF is untagged) and mouse over the color to get the resulting percentages.

Comment: @Wolff, couldn't find anything there, but using the eyedropper under Pitstop Inspect will give me basic object, 75-68-67-90 & then ink coverage, 12.1-12.75-11.75-13.5. Now, while 13.5 is 15% of 90, the math doesn't work on all the other colors.

Comment: Are you sure that PitStop uses the correct CMYK profile when picking the color? I'm not sure, but I think PitStop has some global color setting. If there's some mismatch it could perhaps explain those strange numbers?

Comment: @Wolff currently in Pitstop Preferences > Color Management, I'm seeing CMYK Profile: ISO Coated v2 (ECI) , but under Acrobat Preferences, I'm seeing U.S.Web Coated (SWOP) v2. Does one override the other or should they both match?

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the whole window. In the bottom you can see if the swatch is tagged with a CMYK profile or just untagged CMYK. If it has a CMYK profile it should match the color setting or the numbers will be converted. If it's untagged I don't think it matters. I would just use Acrobat's *Output Preview* and make sure the *Simulation Profile* matches the profile of the swatch (if any). Then you can just mouse over the color and read the values.

Comment: @Wolff sorry, I was off for the past 2 days. ICC Color Profile is none & Color Rendering Intent is default.